# what progression is it in the mario theme song?

Tags: chord-progressions

[image]
it's in key of c and it seems to be Fm7 -Bb7 - C. Is it a change of key here and what function does it provide?
the part before this progression
[image]

Comment: The G#s ought to be Ab, but hey ho. It's in C by the look of it, so is returning to C. But from where? The previous 3 or 4 bars might help.

Comment: @Tim picture 1 is right after picture 2

Answer (score 1):

Trusting solely your guitar sheet music, the chord progression is indeed Fm7/C - Bb7 - C.

From what I recall of fuller versions of the famous Mario theme, there's an Ab in the bass at the first chord of your excerpt, so I often interpret that excerpt as an inflection towards C minor. The repeat snaps back towards C major pretty hard, but the part after the repeat (starts with C-C-C-C-D-E-C-A-G) stays in that C minor-like territory for a little while afterward.

This theme borrows so many chords from the tonic minor that it's tough to completely justify whether it's in C major or when it switches between major and minor, though.